# Перебор масивов через регулярку

Tags: php

Как перебрать многомерный массив ?
Массив.

```
 $array =  array(
'key' => 'value.qwe',
'key2' => 'value2.qwe',
array(
'key3' => 'value3.qwe'
));
```

как мне получить массив где значения будет без .qwe ?

Comment: оно многомерный или двумерный, `.qwe` всегда или произвольные буквы, всегда в конце строки?

Comment: Многомерный, там может быть и 15 вложености.
Всегда .qwe

Comment: array_walk_recursive() с функцией basename($val, '.qwe') внутри коллбэк функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
    $item = str_replace('.qwe', '', $item);
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое